# La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión

Tags: sql, servidor, transact-sql

Estoy tratando insertar muchos registros a una tabla pero no me permite ya que necesito que sean asociados a un mismo id, y me da este error.

```
EXEC [Speed_agregar_proyecto] 
  'BBFE3B40-0EEF-11EB-80D7-00000SFDHJY05061F' 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Speed_agregar_proyecto] @ProyectoId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      IF EXISTS (SELECT proyectoid 
                 FROM   grupos 
                 WHERE  proyectoid = @ProyectoId) 
        INSERT INTO grupostrabajo 
                    (proyectoid, 
                     usuarioid) 
        VALUES     ((SELECT proyectoid 
                     FROM   proyectos 
                     WHERE  proyectoid = @ProyectoId), 
                    (SELECT U.usuarioid 
                     FROM   usuarios AS U 
                            INNER JOIN grupousuariosinavilitados AS GT 
                                    ON GT.idusuario = U.usuarioid 
                     WHERE  estado = 1)) 
  END
```

Comment: Posiblemente tu error se debe a que tu consulta esta devolviendo mas de uno, en tu values

Answer (score 0):

La consulta necesita una refactorización, en lugar de `values()` coloca la consulta que obtiene los datos a insertar, quedando con la forma:

```
 INSERT INTO tabla (campo1, campox) SELECT campo1, campox from ...
```

El valor de proyectoId se puede obtener de la variable `@ProyectoId`, por lo que solo se usaría la consulta para obtener el `usuarioId`.

```
 EXEC [Speed_agregar_proyecto] 
          'BBFE3B40-0EEF-11EB-80D7-00000SFDHJY05061F' 
        
        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Speed_agregar_proyecto] @ProyectoId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
        AS 
          BEGIN 
              IF EXISTS (SELECT proyectoid 
                         FROM   grupos 
                         WHERE  proyectoid = @ProyectoId) 
                INSERT INTO grupostrabajo 
                            (proyectoid, 
                             usuarioid) 
                SELECT @ProyectoId, 
                       U.usuarioid 
                FROM   usuarios AS U 
                       INNER JOIN grupousuariosinavilitados AS GT 
                               ON GT.idusuario = U.usuarioid 
                WHERE  estado = 1 
          END
```

[Referencia](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)